# Grant all NTFS permissions to a security group

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, security-groups

I need to make a security group that will grant NTFS permissions on local computers. How can I make a security group that will give Full Control to local folders (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Common Files\` and `%systemroot%\Temp`)? Will I have to go to each computer and change the access controls for each folder?

Comment: Giving Full Control to `../Common Files` is a huge mistake.  What problem are you trying to solve by doing that.  There is a reason that type of permission, isn't given to users in the Administrator User Group, by default.  Besides all users should already have full control over `../Temp` already.

Answer (score 2):

No single user account or group has full access to everything. You would need to change the permissions of all files and folders to add full access for this new group. **Danger!** Blowing away the standard permissions is a great way to cause difficult system problems; you shouldn't do that.

If you're trying to back up and restore files, you should use an actual backup program. Programs running as administrator (or as users that have been delegated the appropriate authority) can enable `SeBackupPrivilege`, which is an execution mode that allows reads to succeed regardless of ACL, and `SeRestorePrivilege`, which allows writing anywhere. [Read more about privileges at TechNet.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx)

If there are only a couple places you want to get into that only allow access to `SYSTEM`, you could have admins use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) to launch a program as `SYSTEM`. For example, this creates a command prompt running as `SYSTEM`:

```
psexec -s -i cmd.exe
```